# Error on setup:install step 4

Tags: magento2, database, setup

I am installing magento in clean database but it throws an error

```
In StoreRepository.php line 112:
                                                                              
  The store that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.
```

where can be the problem ?
I debugged file and on line 112

```
   if ($store->getId() === null) {
            throw new NoSuchEntityException(
                __("The store ID ({$id}) that was requested wasn't found. Verify the store and try again.")
            );
        }
```

$store->getId is returned as null.

Comment: How are you trying to install Magento? Sounds like you're using a copy/clone of an existing store's source - i.e. source that already has been "in use". It's possible to do this, however you need to clean up your source first (get rid of all the dynamically created files such as var/ generated/, ...) and probably need to delete the env.php in order to start with a fresh database.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in datapatch, set areacode was used.